# Removing DB2INSTDEF value from registry

Tags: db2

Database: DB2 v9.5 on AIX

Scenario: I have 2 instances- db2inst1 and db2inst2. I created db2inst1 first. I went ahead and created db2inst2 next and I do 'db2set -all' on db2inst2 instance I see this:

[g] DB2INSTDEF=db2inst1

I would like to reset DB2INSTDEF and make it not show up when I do 'db2set -all' (other than dropping and recreating db2inst1).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2INSTDEF does not apply on AIX (it's only used on Windows systems), so it doesn't really matter if (or what) it is set to. Why is this a problem?

If you *really* want to eliminate the variable, then run (as root):

```
/opt/IBM/db2/V9.5/adm/db2set -g DB2INSTDEF=
```

(The path `/opt/IBM/db2/V9.5` may be slightly different on your system, depending on whether you installed DB2 into the default location or not).

Comment: It is not a problem. I am just trying to unset it and trying to find out how to do it.